# Node.js: Express-basic-auth wont accept credentials from variable

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to use the basic auth module in express.

When I set the username and password in text, it works with no issues:

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { 'user': 'pass' },
    unauthorizedResponse: getUnauthorizedResponse
}))

function getUnauthorizedResponse(req) {
  console.log(typeof req.auth)
    return req.auth
        ? ('Credentials ' + req.auth.user + ':' + req.auth.password + ' rejected')
        : 'No credentials provided'
}
```

But replace the hardcoded value with a variable, I constantly get 'Credentials rejected'.

```
var user = config["loginUsename"];
var pass = config["loginPassword"];

app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { user: pass },
    unauthorizedResponse: getUnauthorizedResponse
}))

function getUnauthorizedResponse(req) {
  console.log(typeof req.auth)
    return req.auth
        ? ('Credentials ' + req.auth.user + ':' + req.auth.password + ' rejected')
        : 'No credentials provided'
}
```

I console.logged the user and pass variables, the credentials match. I output the req.auth object, it's the same credentials. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. This:

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { user: pass },
    unauthorizedResponse: getUnauthorizedResponse
}))
```

should be:

```
app.use(basicAuth({
    users: { [user]: pass },
    unauthorizedResponse: getUnauthorizedResponse
}))
```

I.e. Your setting username to "user" not as per your config.